# Reason for which a probability is monotonically decreasing

Tags: probability

I have a problem with a proof. I had stochastic and my professor sent us the solution of an exercise.
The exercise was:

Let $S_k$ be the amount of damage of the $k$-th assured. The non-positive random variables $S_k$ are i.i.d with mean $\mu<\infty$ and variance $\sigma^2>0$. Let $\mu$ and $\sigma$ be constant. The annual premium of each assured is calculated by $R_k=\mu+r\cdot\sigma$ while $r>0$ is a risk factor.

Calculate $r$ so small under the side conditions that the sum of $S_k$ is bigger than the sum of $R_k$ with an probability at most 1%.

Now the proof:

Let $\kappa :=1000$ be. Then, we observe the inequality
$$P\left(\sum_{k=1}^\kappa S_k > \kappa\cdot R_k\right)\leq 0.01.\quad (1)$$
We have to calculate the lowest $r$. Because the probability $(1)$ is monotonically decreasing in $r$, we can write the inequality with "=", so:

$$P\left(\sum_{k=1}^\kappa S_k > \kappa\cdot R_k\right)= 0.01.$$

My question is: How can I give a reason that the probability is monotonically decreasing?